# How to create a string from a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm getting an a response from a server which is javascript object which has array in itself, and
I would like to do some operation in client - I would like to simplify that by converting response to some simple kind of string which I would like to display to user, here's the code:

Server response looks like this:

```
0: {productId: 25, productType: 2, productCodes: Array(3)}
1: {productId: 26, productType: 1, productCodes: Array(3)}
length: 2


productCodes: Array(3)
0: {productId: 0, productType: 0, code: "PRODUCT01", desc: "Description1"}
1: {productId: 0, productType: 0, code: "PRODUCT01", desc: "Description2"}
2: {productId: 0, productType: 0, code: "PRODUCT01", desc: "Description3"}
```

How can I convert this to create new array to get something like this:

```
{productType:2, productCodes: "Description1 (PRODUCT01), Description2 (PRODUCT02), Description3 (PRODUCT03)" }
{productType:1...}
```

So basically to create a string which as Description and Code in braces ( ) with comma separated values?

I have tried something like this but this didn't lead me anywhere:

```
// const data = response.data.productCodes.map((currElement, index) => ({
        //   productType = currElement.transactionType,
        //   productCodes = currElement.productCodes.map((elem, index)=>({
        //   }))
 // }));
```

Any kind of help would be awesome!

Thanks !

Comment: You want to use `.map()` on each product to convert it to `Description1 (PRODUCT01)`, and then `.join(', ')` on the result of that to join them all

Comment: The response from that server is presumably a JSON string, rather than a JavaScript object. You create a JavaScript object using JSON.parse() on the returned string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `.map()` on each product to convert it to `Description1 (PRODUCT01)`, and then `.join(', ')` on the result of that to join them all

```js
const products = [
 {productId: 0, productType: 0, code: "PRODUCT01", desc: "Description1"},
 {productId: 0, productType: 0, code: "PRODUCT01", desc: "Description2"},
 {productId: 0, productType: 0, code: "PRODUCT01", desc: "Description3"}];

 const combinedString = products.map(p => `${p.desc} (${p.code})`).join(', ');
 console.log('combinedString:', combinedString);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to join the array elements into a string.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var productCodes = [
  {productId: 0, productType: 0, code: "PRODUCT01", desc: "Description1"},
  {productId: 0, productType: 0, code: "PRODUCT02", desc: "Description2"},
  {productId: 0, productType: 0, code: "PRODUCT03", desc: "Description3"}];
  
  var result = productCodes.map(x=>x.desc+'('+x.code+')');
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  x.innerHTML = result.join();
  // result: Description1(PRODUCT01),Description2(PRODUCT02),Description3(PRODUCT03)
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Using `Array.reduce`, you can generate the combined product string from `productCodes` array.
- Using `Array.map`, you can map the generated combined product string to productCodes item.

```js
const products = [{
  productId: 25,
  productType: 2,
  productCodes: [
    {productId: 0, productType: 0, code: "PRODUCT01", desc: "Description1"},
    {productId: 0, productType: 0, code: "PRODUCT01", desc: "Description2"},
    {productId: 0, productType: 0, code: "PRODUCT01", desc: "Description3"}
  ]
}];

const result = products.map(({ productCodes, ...rest }) => ({
  ...rest,
  productCodes: productCodes.reduce((acc, curV, curI) => (acc += (curI > 0 ? ", " : "") + curV.desc + " (" + curV.code + ")"), '')
}));
console.log(result);
```